# Continuous deployment/integration on Heroku for Java web app

Tags: java, heroku, continuous-integration, continuous-deployment

I have a Java web application that I have managed to successfully deploy and get running on Heroku using the 'git push heroku master' method, but I would like to automate deployment and have a full CI setup. I've had a go at using Atlassian Bamboo with the Heroku plugin but it's really only suitable for standalone .war files - I need to be able to specify additional config via the Procfile definition in my project.

What have other people used for CI/CD of Java web applications to Heroku?

Answer (score 1):

Jenkins has a good Heroku Plugin, that allow you to deploy WARs and interact with Heroku in many ways, including setting variables, scaling your dynos and running one-off processes:

https://github.com/heroku/heroku-jenkins-plugin/blob/master/README.md

To change the Procfile on Heroku, you need to commit and push the new file. You can do that as a step on your CI build. Jenkins can run scripts as part of your build, where you could easily push a new Procfile if that is needed.